Why is Afghanistan experiencing extreme deflation?
This website shows the inflation rates in various countries around the world. Almost all countries have a positive inflation rate; in some of them the rate is quite high. But there is one remarkable exception: in Afghanistan, the inflation rate is about -10% (i.e. the economy is deflating).
Why is the deflation rate in Afghanistan so high? Is this just a numeric coincidence, or does it imply anything about the real economic situation there?

Yes, there's deflation in Afghanistan, according to the World Bank:

Constraints to monetary policy also contributed to the deflationary process. Da Afghanistan Bank (DAB)
has reported a significant decrease in money supply, with M2 contracting by nearly 11 percent from the
fourth quarter of 2020 to the second quarter of 2023. This decline is due to sanctions, frozen assets, banking
disruptions, domestic payment system issues, and a shift to Islamic banking, leading to a cash-dominant
economy. The country's inability to mint new currency, compounded by sanctions that prevent replacing old
banknotes, has further tightened the money supply. Lower currency in circulation has limited access to credit
for consumers and deterred spending, while businesses encounter obstacles in securing investment loans.
Consequently, this is dampening demand for goods and services, prompting businesses to lower prices to
attract customers, exacerbating deflationary trends.
A reduced money supply has also led to an exchange rate appreciation, exacerbating the deflationary
cycle. Since August 2021, the Afghani has appreciated 22.8 percent against the US dollar. This has been
instrumental in mitigating the costs of imported goods, amplifying the deflationary pressures affecting the
economy. It has also rendered Afghanistan's exports pricier on the international market, diminishing their
demand and undercutting Afghanistan's export sector's potential to catalyze economic growth in the postconflict landscape. It is also adding to the widening trade deficit.


So basically the country has deflation because the newly reinstalled Taliban government can't yet print money, so can't cause inflation ("inability to mint new currency"). Additionally, it has minor deflation, because some old paper currency is falling apart from heavy use (opposite of printing money - destroying it). Long term, if they were unable to print money, eventually population growth would also affect deflation (more people (demand) sharing the same amount of cash (supply). Two additional knock-on effects were mentioned also increasing deflation (decreased spending, and price cuts).

What I find puzzling is that, usually, a high inflation is considered a sign of a bad economy. And here, a high deflation is a sign of bad economy.
